# Is there a managed code replacement for Sqlite3 in MonoTouch?

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.ios

I don't trust the native Sqlite3 in MonoTouch anymore. I keep getting random crashes and although I cannot prove it, I claim that it is not my fault.
To verify this I would like to use a managed replacement of Sqlite3.
Is there a project that is syntax compatible with the native version? And more important: does somebody have experience with it?

Comment: Have you filed a bug report with Xamarin?

Comment: To be clear there is **no** *native* sqllite3 in MonoTouch, the **native** part is shipped with iOS itself. What MonoTouch provide are *managed* bindings.

Comment: The bug was reported https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=6680 and it was later found out to be some multithreading issues, where were solved by using the `Serialized` mode, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/8327682/220643 for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the Xamarin cross-platform [MWC sample](http://blog.xamarin.com/2012/02/24/mwc_2012/).

While it use the **native** libsqlite on iOS and Android versions it does use a fully managed port of SQLite for the Windows phone version (where SQLite is not available and where it's not possible to add native code).

However that won't tell you what's wrong with your application. If you're using other native libraries in your project I suggest you to remove them (one by one) and try to duplicate the sqlite crash again.